# css transition old element down and add new element on the top

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js

I have "new element", it's hidden by v-if. When I click on button "display", it will slide a "old element" down and I display a new element on the top. How can I do that with css and javascript?

```html
    <div v-if="display"> new element </div>
    <div> old element </div>
    
    <button> display a new element</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

## Solution 1 : vue transitions

you should use vue transitions if you want the v-if

example :

Template

```html
<Transition name="slide">
   <div v-if="display">New element<div>
</Transition>
<div>New element<div>

<button @click="display = true">
   Display new element
</button>
```

style

```css
.slide-enter-active,
.slide-leave-active {
  transition: 0.5s ease;
}

.slide-enter-to, .slide-leave {
   max-height: 1.5em; // depends on you element height
   overflow: hidden;
}

.slide-enter, .slide-leave-to {
   overflow: hidden;
   max-height: 0;
}
```

(if you don't want the overflow hidden effect you should dig deeper and use transform and opacity to do the trick)

you can read more about vue transitions here :
https://vuejs.org/guide/built-ins/transition.html

---

## Solution 2 : css only

or you can do it with only css using a class `.display_slide-down`

instead of using the `v-if` and `<transition>` you can just use a class that you'll toggle using `:class="display ? 'visible-slide' : ''"`

```html
<div class="newelement" :class="display ? 'visible-slide':''">New element</div>
```

```css
.newelement{
   visibility: hidden;
   overflow: hidden;
   max-height: 0;
}
.newelement.visible-slide{
   visibility: visible;
   max-height: 1.5em;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. How can you animate the old position (like slide down) and then the new one like from left to right?

Comment: the same as before just by playing with css you can use transformX for horizontal and  transformY for vertial or min-width or min-height

you can see more here : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-function/translateX